# Encrypt folder on mac for use on Windows

Tags: macos, windows-xp, encryption

How do I encrypt a folder, preferably with AES, using a Mac OS 10.7, so that I can also use it on Windows? I have tried ISO files, which it seems I can't mount on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads) to encrypt the file and place it in a volume in Mac OS X.

Then, using TrueCrypt in Windows, you can mount the volume (after entering the passphrase of course) and access the file.